# SciPy.optimize.minimize SLSQP ignores bounds and constraints

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a multivariable function using SciPy.optimize.minimize.

I've tried several methods. SLSQP seems to ignore bounds and/or constraints. Obviously something is wrong with how I'm calling minimize but I'm not sure what.

The function (called f in the code) is too complex to describe here. 
I don't have the gradient of f and I don't know the shape.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
....

# fields is an argument (list of strings)
indf1 = fields.index('f1')
indf2 = fields.index('f2')
methods=['Nelder-Mead','SLSQP','L-BFGS-B','COBYLA','Powell']
method_name = methods[1]
cons = ( {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda(x):np.array([x[indf1]])}, {'type':'ineq', 'fun':lambda(x):np.array([x[indf2]])}) 
bounds_pairs = [(None,None) for i in range(len(fields))]
bounds_pairs[indf1] =  (float_info.epsilon,1)
bounds_pairs[indf2] =  (float_info.epsilon,1)
minimize(f,np.array(initial_guess),method=method_name,bounds=bounds_pairs,jac=False,constraints=cons,tol=1e-12)
```

According to both bounds and cons both of the fields f1 and f2 should be non-negative. However, this does not work.

Here is the output:

```
 status: 4
 success: False
 njev: 2
 nfev: 24
 fun: 1000000000000.0
   x: array([  0.00000000e+00,  -4.00000000e-04,  -1.00005897e-04,
    -6.09588623e-13,   1.00000014e-10])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
 jac: array([  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
    -6.71088639e+19,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
 nit: 3
```

When I print out the values of the parameters I can see the negative value assignment:

```
{'f4': 0.0, 'f1': 1.5001161208210954e-08, 'f3': -0.00010000589702911378, 'f2': -6.0958862304687526e-13, 'f5': -0.00040000000000000002}
```

Any leads on this?

*P.S: I have posted a similar question before but got only un-constructive and irrelevant comments.

Comment: It doesn't ignore bounds and constraints. The optimization fails: `success: False`. We can't help without knowing f. Is your initial_guess in bounds?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad the initial guess is in bounds. I know that the optimization fails. It looks like the reason for failure is 'Inequality constraints incompatible'. 
f is a non-trivial algorithm that outputs a scalar after a few minutes of execution.

Comment: numerical optimization is about optimizing smooth functions. You can not simply calculate values with a complex algorithm and expect to get a minimum.

Comment: Based on the error message, your problem is probably badly scaled. Try applying scaling factors (and potentially also offsets) to the `x` variables so that typical values of all entries are of order 1. Bad scaling breaks among other things the finite difference approximation of the Jacobian.

Comment: @cel - I can't see how the fact that my function is not smooth "allows" a very popular software package that solves a very common problem to misbehave/wrong error message/ignoring what it's supposed to do, etc.
Am I using the wrong optimization method here? I know that people are optimizing complex processes all the time.

Comment: @Zahy, that makes no sense, you cannot expect that an algorithm designed to minimize smooth functions will work on any function, just because you are using a common purpose library. This seems to be a classical case of garbage in garbage.

Comment: @Zahy: numerical minimization algorithms generally make assumptions of properties of the function. For SLSQP, I explain one assumption above required in addition to smoothness, and how to avoid problems in this regard. Mathematically equivalent problem formulations are not necessarily the same for convergence properties of a given algorithm.